# Obtaining User Profile Information IN JSON

Tags: android, json

Iam doing in project where i need google account information details after login to google.I was trying to get the information about google account in JSON.How could I do that??

Comment: may be you can try scribe oauth library for retrieving the data in json format.just google you can find some information on this.

Answer (score 0):

may be you can try scribe oauth library for retrieving the data in json format.just google you can find some information on this